# Is 2^64 enough for centuries?

Tags: evm, bignumber

I want my smart contract to lock funds for 100 years. Somebody may use it to lock funds for even more time.

Will 2^64 "markets" (anyone can create a new consecutively numbered market) be enough to be sure of no overflow during that time?

Ethereum may become much faster in the future.

So, should I use 2^64 or 2^128 maximum number of "markets"?

Comment: Without more details is hard to make an assertion that 64 or 128 will be enough. Fifty years ago 32 bits seemed like infinite but were are closer to Y2K38 and unix is more present than ever was. From a disk space perspective `2^64` entries occupy around 590 exabytes. It is a lot but large companies handle around petabytes os it is within reach. For comparison `2^128` occupy `10^16` yottabytes so it will be out of reach for quite some time I guess.

Comment: 2 ^ 64 is 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 (base 10), so quite large. You might find that the expected gas savings using < 256 bits are not actually there, in practice. It is worth confirming before compromising precision/magnitude.